# Input field validation in Node.js Express.js Mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'm new to Node.js I'm trying to transfer all I did before to this environment.

I'm using Express.js with Mongoose.

I come from a ASP.NET MVC environment where I'm used to define my model and then automatically scaffolding the form with personalized HTML.

I'd like to know if there's a way to scaffold form for edit insert and a way to go for input validation on single fields.

I've looked here http://plugins.mongoosejs.com but I didn't find what I needed.

Comment: could you please explain it a bit more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If you are just starting the study Express, then play with [express-validator](https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator) with this micro [tutorial](http://blog.ijasoneverett.com/2013/04/form-validation-in-node-js-with-express-validator/)
- or use Mongo's build in **[validators](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html)**

Comment: I've seen the tutorial. It's nice, but I'm looking for a way to validate each input with a class and an error message shown close to the referred error.

Comment: @Mino use build in validators